# C++ Command line action abstraction using interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost, stl, command-line-arguments

I'm building an application whose usage is going to look something like this:

```
application --command --option1=? --option2=2?
```

Basically, there can be any number of options, but only one command per instance of the application. Similar to the way git works.

Now, I thought I'd write it in C++ to get some boost and stl experience and have a go with a few of those design patterns I keep reading about. So, I implemented this:

```
class Action
{
public:
    void AddParameter(std::string key, boost::any p);
    virtual unsigned int ExecuteAction();

protected:
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> parameters;
};
```

I'll explain my logic anyway, just to check it - this is an abstract-ish action. All actions need option adding, hence the parameters map, so that we can implement at this level, but we expect `ExecuteAction` to be implemented by derived classes, such as my simple example `DisplayHelpAction`, which does pretty much what it says on the tin.

So now I've written a factory, like so:

```
class DetermineAction
{
public:
    DetermineAction();
    vx::modero::Action getAction(std::string ActionString);
private:
    std::map<std::string, vx::modero::Action> cmdmap;
};
```

The logic being that the constructor will create a map of possible strings you can ask for and getAction will do what it says - give it a command string and it'll give you a class that is derived from `Action` which implements the desired functionality.

I'm having trouble with that constructor. I am trying this:

```
this->cmdmap = std::map<std::string, Action>();
this->cmdmap.insert(pair<string, Action>("help", DisplayHelpAction()));
this->cmdmap.insert(pair<string, Action>("license", DisplayLicenseAction()));
```

Which is causing a lot of errors. Now, I'm used to the Java Way of interfaces, so you use:

```
Interface I = new ConcreteClass();
```

and Java likes it. So that's the sort of idea I'm trying to achieve here, because what I want do have for the implementation of `getAction` is this:

```
return this->cmdmap[ActionString];
```

Which should return a class derived from Action, on which I can then start adding parameters and call execute.

So, to summarise, I have two questions which are closely related:

- Soundboard. I'm deliberately practising abstracting things, so there's some additional complexity there, but in principle, is my approach sound? Is there an insanely obvious shortcut I've missed? Is there a better method I should be using?
- How can I set up my class mapping solution so that I can return the correct class? The specific complaint is link-time and is:

  ```
  Linking CXX executable myapp
  CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/abstractcmd.cpp.o: In function `nf::Action::Action()':
  abstractcmd.cpp:(.text._ZN2vx6modero6ActionC2Ev[_ZN2vx6modero6ActionC5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for nf::Action'
  ```

Just because it might be relevant, I'm using `boost::program_options` for command line parsing.

---

**Edit 1**: Ok, I have now replaced `Action` with `Action*` as per Eugen's answer and am trying to add `new SomethingThatSubclassesAction` to the map. I'm still getting the vtable error.

Comment: If --command isn't optional, drop the dashes (i.e. make it an "argument" instead of an "option").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One thing than needs to be said right off the bat is that runtime polymorphism works in C++ via pointers to the base class not by value. So your `std::map<std::string, Action>` needs to be `std::map<std::string, Action*>` or your derived Actions (i.e. `DisplayHelpAction`) will be [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) when copied into the `map`. Storing `Action*` also mean that you'll need to explicitly take care of freeing the `map` values when you're done. **Note**: you can use a [boost::ptr_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html) (`boost::ptr_map<std::string,Action>`) (as @Fred Nurk pointed out) or a [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) (`std::map<std::string,boost::shared_ptr<Action> >`) to not worry about explicitly freeing the `Action*` allocated.
   The same thing about 'Action getAction(std::string ActionString);' it needs to become `Action* getAction(std::string ActionString);`.
2. The linker error is (most likely) caused by not providing an implementation for `virtual unsigned int ExecuteAction();`. Also I'd say it makes sense to make it pure virtual (`virtual unsigned int ExecuteAction() = 0;`) - in which case you don't need to provide an implementation for it. It will also provide the closes semantics to a Java interface for the `Action` class.
3. Unless you have a very good reason for the `Action` derived objects to not know the entire `boost:program_options` I'd pass it down and let each of them access it directly instead of constructing `std::map<std::string, boost::any>`.
4. I'd rename `DetermineAction` to something like `ActionManager` or `ActionHandler`.

Comment: And that fixes it, for which you can have a green tick. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ninefingers: I thought you wanted some critiques for the overall design, but thank you...

Comment: @Eugen I'm still open to them if someone wants to drop by and give a few. However, since your immediate reaction wasn't `no stopit!` I feel a little more reassured that this isn't entirely the wrong way to be going. There are some things that there are obvious better ways of doing - I was worried this was one of them - and I wanted to encourage people to shout if there was a `boost::miracle` class I should be using instead. Also, usually, if there was an obvious better way, stackoverflow's user base would probably already have said so!

Comment: Use a boost::ptr_map if you want to dynamically allocate the Actions; *much* easier than freeing them in an exception-safe way.

Comment: @Fred ah. See. Thankyou. Shame comments don't attract rep, really.

Comment: @Ninefingers: If you're here for the rep, you're Doing It Wrong™. :)

Comment: @Fred I meant that as a way to give you rep for the advice. I'm here for the learning, but I like to give credit where credit is due too. Personally rep stopped being interesting past 3k.

Comment: @Ninefingers: just made it to 3k, tnx for spoiling it for me... [jk]