# C++ boost::ptr_map with abstract base class causing insertion issues

Tags: c++, boost

Following on from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998495/c-command-line-action-abstraction-using-interface) I have an abstract base class `Action` which acts as an interface for executing various different actions. In order to implement an abstraction layer, I have an ActionHandler class that stores various actions in this:

```
class ActionHandler
{
public:
    ActionHandler();
    ~ActionHandler();
    Action& getAction(std::string ActionString);
private:
    boost::ptr_map<std::string, vx::modero::Action> cmdmap;
};
```

I'm given to understand from the responses to my previous question that boost automatically handles freeing of any inserted pointer types (classes) into this map.

So, I now try inserting things derived from `Action`, this happens in the constructor of ActionHandler (ActionHandler::ActionHandler):

```
ActionHandler::ActionHandler()
{
    this->cmdmap.insert("help", new DisplayHelpAction());
};
```

Where `DisplayHelpAction` publicly subclasses `Action`. Doing so causes this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::ptr_map<std::basic_string<char>, 
Action>::insert(const char [5], DisplayHelpAction*)’
```

Now, from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map_adapter.html) the method I'm using is:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool>  insert( key_type& k, T* x );
```

So as far as I can see, using polymorphism here should work. I don't want to use `boost::any` because I don't want this list to contain *any* type of pointer. It should conform to the interface specified by `Action` or not be there.

So, what am I doing wrong?

I can fall back on simply using `std::map` and have my destructor `delete`, so if this can't be reasonably achieved it isn't a show stopper. I personally think `shared_ptr` with `std::map` might be better, but having experimented with this, I now have so-why-doesn't-this-work syndrome.

Comment: Does DisplayHelpAction publicly derive from Action? Is the `this->...` call located in a non-const member function? There is too little context here. Please fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you pointed out, the method you're calling is

```
std::pair<iterator,bool>  insert( key_type& k, T* x );
```

but the first argument is not of a type that can be bound to a non-const reference to `std::string`. You would have to either make the key an lvalue

```
std::string key = "help";
cmdmap.insert(key, new DisplayHelpAction());
```

Or use the form that takes a const reference (still has to be two lines, for exception safety)

```
std::auto_ptr<DisplayHelpAction> ptr(new DisplayHelpAction());
cmdmap.insert("help", ptr);
```

Comment: +1 The missing 'const' in the function's declaration looks like a bug. Maybe someone should raise this issue in the Boost mailing list.

Comment: This explains why the key is passed by non-const reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/faq.html#why-does-ptr-map-t-insert-replace-take-two-arguments-the-key-and-the-pointer-instead-of-one-std-pair-and-why-is-the-key-passed-by-non-const-reference

Comment: I should note though that using this method, boost doesn't like my pure virtual `Action` though; I have to use a normal `virtual`. I am assuming there is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: @sellibitze: it's perfectly intentional (exception safety reason), I've added a lengthy answer that will hopefully explains why.

Answer (score 9):

@Cubbi's answer is correct, but doesn't explain why it has been done so.

Traditionally, the arguments are taken by `const&`, unless they are built-in, so one would naturally expect:

```
insert(key_type const&, value*)
```

Which would naturally allow:

```
someMap.insert("abc", new DerivedAction());
```

But the authors chose the signature:

```
insert(key_type&, value*)
```

And yes, it is **intentional**.

The problem is that the form taking a raw pointer is expected to be used with an *inlined* `new`, as you demonstrated in your own example, however there is an exception safety issue.

You can read Sutter's take on it at [Guru Of The Week](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm).

When a function is called in C++, all its arguments should be evaluated before the call begins, and the order of evaluation of the arguments is unspecified. There is a risk, therefore, if the evaluation of arguments performs a memory allocation *AND* another operation (that may throw). In your example:

```
insert("abc", new DerivedAction());

// equivalent to

insert(std::string("abc"), new DerivedAction());
```

There are two operations to be done (in unspecified order) before the call can be executed:

- the conversion of `"abc"` into a `std::string`
- the construction on the free-store of a `DerivedAction` object

If the conversion of `"abc"` into a `std::string` throws, and it was scheduled *after* the memory allocation, then memory is leaked, because you have no way to free it.

By forcing the first argument NOT to be a temporary, they prevented this mistake. It is not sufficient (in general) since any function call could be performed and still throw, but it does make you think, does it not :) ?

*Note: the version taking an `auto_ptr` by reference does so the other way around, they force you to allocate the memory beforehand, so the conversion of `"abc"` possibly throwing is not a risk any longer because RAII will ensure proper clean-up*

Comment: +1 for the additional detail and clarification, that actually makes sense since the objective was to avoid having to explicitly free my `std::map`. I've actually, having asked this, gone with the other suggestion from the original (that is, `shared_ptr`) since it works with a pure virtual function in `Action`. The idea wasn't to allow people to instantiate `Action`, since there isn't any reason for it, but now I'm wondering if that is a problem or not. I might have another question brewing now...!

Answer (score 1):

You need either to pass value using `auto_ptr`:

```
std::auto_ptr<Action> action (new DisplayHelpAction ());
cmdmap.insert ("help", action);
```

... or create key before you invoke `insert` so that it will be passes as non-const reference, in which case you don't need auto pointer:

```
std::string key ("help");
cmdmap.insert (key, new DisplayHelpAction());
```

In the second example, usage is enforced by making key reference non-constant in the `ptr_map_adapter` class. Otherwise, the object you have allocated to insert to the map could leak if `std::string` throws exception.